# Sharing a mongoid model between 2 applications - using engine vs. plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, rails-engines

I want to share a model between 2 (maybe more in the future) of my rails apps. I couldn't find any clear suggestions, but I picked up some of the questions and answers I've read and came to a conclusion that it has to be done with a "gemmed" plugin engine. 
I decide to go with an plugin, because I read that engine is simply a kind of a "full" plugin.

So I created a plugin using: `rails plugin new my_models --skip-active-record --skip-test-unit --dummy-path=spec/dummy` (the options are for skipping activerecord as an ORM and using rspec for testing).

After I created the plugin, I got the following files:

```
my_models.gemspec  Gemfile  Gemfile.lock  lib  MIT-LICENSE  Rakefile  README.rdoc  spec
```

I tried to include the model using the following methods:

1. Just creating an `app/models` directory and put my model inside
2. As suggested in [this tutorial](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/23/a-guide-to-starting-your-own-rails-engine-gem/) (and I could see in [devise's github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/generators/mongoid/devise_generator.rb)), I created a generator in an attempt to generate the model.

Both of them failed, and then I decided to go with the engine suggestion (by just adding `--mountable` to the options list of the "rails new" command), I got the full rails app structure (with app, bin, db and the rest of the directories), put my model in the app/models dir and it worked like a magic!

As I believe I'm a programmer and not I magician, I don't to do such magics, so can you tell me what's wrong with both of my thin plugin solutions (using generator/creating a model)?? Moreover, what are the advantages of using those generators?

I'm attaching my generator's code, maybe I miss something:

```
require 'rails/generators/named_base'
require 'mongoid'

module Mongoid
  module AttackGenerator
    def generate_model
      invoke "mongoid:model", [name] unless model_exists? && behavior == :invoke
    end

    def inject_field_types
      inject_into_file model_path, migration_data, after: "include Mongoid::Document\n" if model_exists?
    end

    def migration_data
      field :link_url, type: String
      field :token, type: String
    end

    def model_exists?
      File.exists?(File.join(destination_root, model_path))
    end

    def model_path
      @model_path ||= File.join("app", "models", "#{file_path}.rb")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: With the non-full engine/plugins you might need to `require` the files from the parent application. If they are already on the load path you can do `require 'my_engine/whatever`, otherwise `require MyEngine::Engine.root.join('app', 'models', 'whatever')`.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment about being a programmer, not a magician, but by the time you're using Rails you've completely surrendered to the realm of magic. You have to learn the spells and incantations, and if you go too far in trying to understand them, it will be like staring at the sun.

Comment: I might be wrong but the concept of plugin was something "legacy" which worked in rails 2 (not sure if in 3 still worked), maybe the generator is there only for that purposes. Currently, creating an engine it's as simple as having a Railtie in a simple gem built with `bundle gem gem_name`, the `app` directory and a few minor things. Although I must admit that in your specific situation, it doesn't feel like you need an engine, you can go with a simple gem

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL 
What's the difference between an engine and a simple gem? How can I create a gem which is neither an engine nor a plugin?

Comment: Actually I forgot about migrations, you need an engine. I added an answer with further details. A gem is basically a library, an engine is still a gem but with a file `engine.rb` (loaded in the gem) which enhance gem capabilities with autoloading app directory and other stuff. See my answer for details. It's long and requires you to study various stuff, but they are very interesting and once you understand it, you'll understand much more "rails magic" ;)

Answer (score 0):

An [engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) (very good guide) is basically a small Rails app: has controllers, can inject into your rails code in various ways (sharing classes/controllers and such) and most important, can use your main Rails application code transparently.

After thinking a bit about it, I believe you **need an engine**, the reason is, a simple model still require migrations. Notice that an engine is basically a gem plus some few additions provided by rails.

Although miguiding (plugins in rails are not used anymore), the command `rails plugin new blorgh --mountable` creates a **gem** which is a rails engine.

How do you understand if a gem is a rails engine? By the file `engine.rb` (can be named differently, the contents are the important stuff).

```
module Blorgh
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Blorgh
  end
end
```

The other important thing you should be aware of, is that rails (actually `Bundler.require`) auto `require`s **one file** for you when you add your custom gem to your gemfile: the file named `lib/yourgemname.rb`, in this case, `lib/blorgh.rb`. That's your entry point.
Aside from that, all the other things (gemspec and all the other files) are things created for rubygems. The important part is that you use `.gemspec` file as your gemfile, just add gems using `add_dependency` instead of the standard Gemfile syntax. If you want (and you should) learn more about ruby gems, [this article](https://quickleft.com/blog/engineering-lunch-series-step-by-step-guide-to-building-your-first-ruby-gem/) is really good

The `app` directory is autoloaded like rails does, so adding `app/models/yourmodel.rb` is a good way to have your model autoloaded and shared with all your apps.
The last important thing, are migrations. You have to remember to run `your_engine_name:install:migrations` in your Rails app to copy your migrations from your engine to your rails app and run them (otherwise you can see the suggestions on [this article](http://pivotallabs.com/leave-your-migrations-in-your-rails-engines/))

And you are ready. One note! To install your gem you have two options: use your remote git repository (best option) or for local development you can use `:path`, here two examples that can be added to your Rails apps gemfiles:

```
# Use this only for development purposes
gem 'yourgem', '1.0.0', path: 'your/local/path/to/gem'

# Use this for deploy and such, you'll need access to that repository
gem 'yourgem', '1.0.0', git: 'yourgiturl'
```

This should be enough